# Android Studio:failed to resolve:com.leaking.slideswitch:app:1.0.0

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am looking for help on the resolving issue with Android Gradle.

in the /app/build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.leaking.slideswitch:app:1.0.0'
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven{
        url 'http://xlab-tech.com:45682/nexus/content/groups/public/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

}

But messages Gradle Sync：

```
Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.leaking.slideswitch:app:1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.leaking.slideswitch` is not published in maven anymore, to be confirmed you can search [there](http://search.maven.org/). What I can suggest is just create a new class called **SlideSwitch.java** and copy all codes from [here](https://github.com/Leaking/SlideSwitch/blob/master/SlideSwitch/src/com/leaking/slideswitch/SlideSwitch.java). Then You can do your task as usual. Hope this may help.